# How to add .NET Framework 3.5 and other prerequisites to InstallShield project

Tags: c#, windows-installer, installshield, prerequisites

I can create setup file in InstallShield 2009

I don't know how to add the .NET Framework 3.5 and other prerequisites to the InstallShield project.

---

i creae installscript project in instalshield2009   it has not
"Redistributables view."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

InstallShield provides the prerequisites functionality. You can use this in your MSI project. This would ensure that these prerequisites are only installed if they are not already present in the target machine.

If you do not want to include these components like .NET Framework 3.5 into your installer then you can use the redistributable setup installer. 
.net 3.5 redistributable setup installer is about 3MB and when this is included into the prerequisites of your InstallShiled project then the installer will check if .net 3.5 framework is already installed on the target machine and if not it will prompt the user and download the entire .net 3.5 framework and install it.

you can [check this](http://community.flexerasoftware.com/forumdisplay.php?f=133) out for if you have very specific Install Shield queries.

Answer (score 2):

For .NET Framework 3.5 redistributables, you need to add the appropriate Microsoft .NET Framework prerequisite. That's done through the Redistributables view.

For InstallShield 2009, follow the instructions [here.](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q200284)